# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined - rendering contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Getting the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined when I tried to render the elements with togglePersonsHandler to get the content which is inside the personsState. The goal is to get the contents by clicking on the button.

Here is my App.js file

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './person/Person';

const App = props => {
  const [ personsState ] = useState({
    persons: [
      { name: 'Maxmillian', age: 28 },
      { name: 'Manu', age: 18 },
      { name: 'Stephanie', age: 24 }
    ],
    otherState: 'some other value',
    showPersons: false
  });


  const switchNameHandler = (newName) => {
    // console.log('Was clicked!');
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: newName, age: 28 },
        { name: 'Manu', age: 18 },
        { name: 'Stephanie', age: 24 }
      ]
    });
  };

  const nameChangedHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      persons: [
        { name: 'Max', age: 28 },
        { name: event.target.value, age: 18 },
        { name: 'Stephanie', age: 24 }
      ]
    })
  };

  const togglePersonsHandler = () => {
    const doesShow = this.state.showPersons;
    this.setState({showPersons: !doesShow});
  }
    
    const style = {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      font: 'inherit',
      border: '1px solid blue',
      padding: '8px',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    };
  
  
    return (
        <div className="App">
          <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
          <p>This is really working!</p>
          <button 
            style={style}
            onClick={togglePersonsHandler}>Switch Name</button>
          { 
            this.state.showPersons === true ?
            <div>
              <Person 
                name={personsState.persons[0].name} 
                age={personsState.persons[0].age} />
              <Person 
                name={personsState.persons[1].name} 
                age={personsState.persons[1].age} 
                click={switchNameHandler.bind(this, 'Max!')}
                changed={nameChangedHandler}>My Hobbies: Racing</Person>
              <Person 
                name={personsState.persons[2].name} 
                age={personsState.persons[2].age} />
            </div> : null
          }
        </div>
      );
    }

  // ein Element entwickeln
  // return React.createElement('div', {className: 'App'}, React.createElement('h1', null, 'Work'));

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

And here the Person.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './Person.css';

const person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="Person">
            <p onClick={props.click}>I'm {props.name} and I am {props.age} years old. </p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed} value={props.name} />
        </div>
    )
};

export default person;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for the support!

Comment: Please read how to use useState hook. You are doing it wrong. there is no this.setState in state hook.

Answer (score 2):

`this.state` and `this.setState` is only available in class components extending `React.component`. You're using a functional component, therefore you need to use hooks to update the state. I suggest to create a separate state for `showPersons`:

```
const [ showPersons, setShowPersons ] = useState(false);

const togglePersonsHandler = () => {
    setShowPersons(!showPersons);
}
```

If you only want one state, add a setter:

```
const [ personsState, setPersonsState ] = useState({...});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Additional to your solution, I changed the syntax of the showPersons to if(showPersons)-condition with the elements inside